# Add .addEventListener to a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, addeventlistener

I have this following .js function:

```
function basketHandler(basket)
{
                if (basket != null)
{
                                if(basket.Tickets.length > 0)
                                {
                                                console.log("Basket is not null and has tickets");
                                }
                                else
                                { 
                                                console.log("Basket is not null but has no tickets");
                                }
                }
                else
                {
                                console.log("Basket is null");
                }
}
```

and I have been told I need to add an event listener to it, underneath the function, for it to work and output the relevant console.logs. So after the functions I have tried the following with no joy...

```
basket.addEventListener("EVENTNAME", eventhandler)

basket.addEventListener("onload", basketHandler);

document.addEventListener("onload", basketHandler);

element.addEventListener("onload", basketHandler);
```

I am sure there is something fundamental I am missing, I can see the errors this code brings up in the console, but I don't know what they mean, so its difficult for me to fix it blindly... I don't have a great grasp of Javascript so I'm probably truing to run before I can walk, but either way, it's something I need to get working... any help greatly appreciated.

EDIT - In response to: @David Thomas: The errors I'm getting in the console are just Uncaught ReferenceError: basket is not defined depending on which variation I try.

EDIT - I am also linked to a .js library here: https://tickets.leicesterymca.co.uk/Iframe/esrojsapi.js if that helps.

Comment: What is `basket`?

Comment: I'm trying to get a basket or a 'my cart' page working for a theatre website. I have been given the function and then told I need to add the event listener to listen our for the basket status and then it will execute the if statement and show the console logs.

Comment: "*I can see the errors this code brings up in the console…*" – great, can we see them too?

Comment: So what is `basket`, where is it defined, how is it being passed to your function? Incidentally, if you're using `addEventListener()` the first argument supplied to the event-handler will be the `Event` object, and within the function you can either use `Event.target` to find the element on which the event was originally triggered, or simply `this` to access the element upon which the event-handler was bound.

Comment: Really sorry, I'm struggling with that and a little lost - I was told to link in their .js library before hand - So perhaps basket is defined in there and relates to some other functions? Here's the library I'm linking to: https://tickets.leicesterymca.co.uk/Iframe/esrojsapi.js

Comment: Have you checked the resources tab of your browser's dev tools, or the console, to ensure that library is being loaded? Can you show enough of your code that we can reproduce your problem? Please: read both the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidelines, hopefully it might help you [edit] your question into a state in which it can be answered without blind guesses.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). You're confusing it with the IE-only [`attachEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: oh ok... so ill try those variations with the add instead of the attach?

Comment: I have changed this in the question, thank you - also I have changed it in my code but still nothing...

Comment: @Shaun: please don't invalidate answers by changing the code in your question; instead [edit] your question to add details, such as "in response to Joseph's answer I tried using `addEvent!istener()`, as shown below <show the code you used>, which also failed <explain how it failed>."

Comment: Ok no problem, apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
    basketHandler(basket);
});
```

Comment: Thanks you - I see this error though: Uncaught ReferenceError: basket is not defined...

Comment: maybe you should define this variable, what is basket exactly ?

Comment: What is basket? Is it an Object?

I can see the function with a parameter "basket", but this object can calls different in your implementation.

Comment: I tried a mix of your code and came out with this: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", basketHandler); - and I now only have an error on the length line: if(basket.Tickets.length > 0) - so I don't know if that means its working ok and the length line is written wrong?